# How to access IP address & port of node in another node in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, service, dns

I have an application with 2 pods, where one pod is ingesting data and other wants to consume it.
I am trying with single node Kubernetes setup.
Right now:

```
`in pod1` 
        - name: ingest_cfg
        value: zmq_tcp,0.0.0.0:9000 [where pod1 is publishing on port 9000, even this I want to be dynamically configurable]

`in pod2`
        - name: ingest_cfg
        value: "zmq_tcp,IPadd:pv" [where IPadd should be Ip address where pod 1 is publishing and pv is port number where pod1 has published]
```

Now, I need to know how can I configure this in code. I don't want to hard code the IP address & port. Any pointers will be very helpful.
I have tried using service name but that points to cluster IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you're using a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) for each of your apps. Create a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) on top of each of the Deployments. And then from the data consumer you can point to the internal dns service provided by kubernetes.

Let's said your service for data ingestion is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: ingestion
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
```

You can use the dns of `myservice.default.svc.cluster.local`.

Comment: Will it not work in case I have a pod rather than deployment ?  And in pod2, in the environment variables- I should write my-service instead of IPadd:pv ? But this doesn't work

Comment: Yes, the Pod spec also has an optional subdomain field which can be used to specify its subdomain. For example, a Pod with hostname set to “foo”, and subdomain set to “bar”, in namespace “my-namespace”, will have the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) “foo.bar.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example”. See this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods